# How to copy a file to a destination with administrator permission

Tags: java, file, permissions

I have created a desktop application using java to copy a file to the root directory. It works fine when I use the excecutable jar file out side the C:\ directory. But It when I use it inside the C:\Program Files (x86) directory, it throws an exception 'io.IOException:Access is denied'

my code is as follows.

```
File jrxml_source = new File(new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\Reports\\Default.jrxml"); 
File jrxml_destination = new File(new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\Reports\\Tested.jrxml");

if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try {
        source = new RandomAccessFile(jrxml_source, "rw").getChannel();
        destination = new RandomAccessFile(jrxml_destination , "rw").getChannel();

        long position = 0;
        long count = source.size();

        source.transferTo(position, count, destination);
    }finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It "might" work if the executed was evaluated to admin level, although, I'd HIGHLY discourage this as it opens up another can of worms. A better solution might be to place the file into a "well known" location, like `{user.home}\AppData\Local\{your app}`

Comment: I want to distribute the excecutable file to number of users. so, they should be able to install the executable anywhere they whish. I feel its much more batter to allow users to do anything.

Comment: So? Windows may not allow you to "install" it "anywhere they wish" - this is a restriction imposed by the OS, with a common, recommend solution

Comment: Usually, we can copy a file manually with a popup permission dialog. I want to copy the file with that permission programatically.

Comment: Java won't do this, you'll need to look at a native solution

Comment: InstallAnyWhere? may be some tools could help in this.

Comment: Thank you @Raju Sharma, let me try out moreon this. could you please let me know if you have any idea about the tools?

Comment: "InstallAnyWhere" is a tool, you can read more on this from http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installanywhere2013/Content/helplibrary/ia_gs_tutorials.htm

Comment: InstallAnywhere is a program to install the application. my question is only about the permission to copy any files via an executable file which already built. I have used Install Creator Pro to make exe installer for my application.

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer. your solution is the suitable one for my app.